# encoding problem at request with json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, encoding

I request a JSON file from a server, apparently the file is sent with the wrong encoding header. Unfortunately I don't have the possibility to change the header, because I don't have access to the server.
The response contains the strings as Unicode codepoint, e.g. "\u00c3\u00a4". When I parse the result as JSON it converts to "Ã¤" expected would be "ä".

I am loading the response with Axios, I have already tried to load and convert the response as ArrayBuffel but haven't found the right way yet.

What can I do to correct the encoding on the client side without any adjustments on the server?

example response:

```
{
  "uid": "",
  "title": "my name",
  "gender": "2",
  "address_title": "",
  "address_firstname": "my",
  "address_lastname": "name",
  "address_zip": "99999",
  "address_city": "x\u00c3\u00bcxx",
  "address_street": "Bahn Stra\u00c3\u0178e 1",
  "address_name2": "",
  "address_name3": "",
  "phone": "5555",
  "phone_emergency": "55555",
  "fax": "",
  "email": "mail@mail",
  "internet": "",
  "address_alternative_street": "",
  "address_alternative_zip_city": "",
  "job_description": "G\u00c3\u00a4rtner",
  "emergency_opening": "",
  "emergency_opening2": "10 - 11 und 17 - 18 Uhr",
  "emergency_description": "",
  "latitude": "",
  "longitude": ""
}
```

[response headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9K69.png)

Comment: do you mean the address_city has wrong unicode?

Comment: When I parse the result as JSON it converts to "Ã¤" expected would be "ä"

Comment: @lotterfriends tried it in an online tool and it also convert it Ã¤

Comment: I don't speak JS but in python `"\u00c3\u00a4".encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')` returns `'ä'` (_Latin Small Letter A With Diaeresis_).